# dnscrypt-proxy is missing from debian 12, going to install it via sid?

Tags: debian, apt, backports, dnscrypt

Given this discussion: https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/discussions/2410

It seems that **dnscrypt-proxy** has a dependency called `powerman` used only for testing and not useful in the main pagackage that made it unable to compile and it was not fixed before the last freeze of ***debian 12 bookworm***.

The end result of having the package `dnscrypt-proxy` not present in debian 12 !!!

---

For my config I need `dnscrypt-proxy` package.

**The remaining options are:**

- Install it from http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dnscrypt-proxy/ however that would be a static installation, hence making it not updated in case of security fixes.
- Otherwise because it was fixed after debian12 release it is possible to pull it from debian **sid**.

(I searched and it seems that isn't available from backports)

---

**What is the best practice that allows me to not break the debian installation integrating that only package from sid ? Should I use apt pinning ?**

Bard suggested me also this syntax for *sources.list*:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/sid main/dnscrypt-proxy
```

but it clearly doesn't work.